Postgres: How to check if user can grant privilege on a table without using information_schema.role_table_grants?
I need to find a way of checking if some privilege on the table (select, update, etc) is grantable using pg_catalog. I could only find a way to see if privilege is grantable with the use of information_schema.role_table_grants (column is_grantable), but in my task I can't use information_schema, only pg_catalog.
Please, share some knowledge on this question. I feel like I've checked every view in pg_catalog already.
I've checked all the views, even slightly by name related to roles in pg_catalog. Couldn't find anything.

References to the requisite sytem catalogs and views can be found by querying information_schema.views to get the view_definition for role_table_grants. The definition might include addition references to information_schema views, so you'll need to walk through the definitions to create a query that doesn't reference viewsi in information_schema.
